# How to disable Edit mode in the QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QTableView. It's working fine. But the problem is that if I double click the cell then it changes into edit mode. I need to disable the edit option. How to do that?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use the following:

```
QTableView table(...);
table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
```

Comment: This worked for me too when I had had a similar issue, quick tip though, it's actually `QAbstractItemView`, not `QAbstractView`

Answer (score 10):

Try QAbstractItemView, which is the baseclass of QTableView where the EditTriggers enum (which NoEdittriggers is an element of) is declared. Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023435/what-is-qabstractview-in-qt-this-statement) link.

```
QTableView table(...);
table.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
```

Comment: This should have more upvotes, it's actually more correct than the accepted answer which has an important typo

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`editTriggers property`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop) to change the behaviour.
All possible values are described [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum).

```
QTableView view();
view.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
```

Comment: You should probably create an example in your solution. The link you used is broken and the answer doesn't really offer much help on its own.