# what is QAbstractView in QT (this statement)?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I am attempting to disable editing in my table view. I came across [this](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11451/) thread which states that you could do the following

```
tableView.setEditTriggers(QAbstractView::NoEditTriggers);
```

My question is what is the QAbstractView here ?

Comment: that seems to be a typo and should read QAbstractItemView., which is the baseclass of QTableView where the EditTrigger enum (which NoEdittriggers is an element of) is declared.

Comment: Thanks  could you put that as answer so that I mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that seems to be a typo and should read [QAbstractItemView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html), which is the baseclass of QTableView where the [EditTriggers](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum) enum (which NoEdittriggers is an element of) is declared.